# Is there any difference in bash between "while read -r line; do ...; done < file` and `cat file | while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done`?

Tags: bash

I'm learning bash and I found a tutorial on internet that says these are the same:

```
while read -r line;
do
    ...
done < file

$ cat file | while IFS= read -r line;
do
    ...
done
```

Are there any subtle differences in these two loops are are they really the same?

Comment: my suggestion: Don't parse the output of `cat` command.

Comment: To amplify what chepner has already touched on: In general `cat foo | bar` as opposed to `bar <foo` (1) is less inefficient for two reasons: (1a) creation of a pipeline requires an extra fork(); (1b) causing `foo` to first be read by `cat`, then written into a pipeline, then read from the pipeline by `bar`, is less efficient than simply letting content in `foo` be directly read by `bar`. (2) in cases where `bar` is a program which has access to the `seek()` call (not typically available for bash unless you've written a C extension), giving it a pipeline rather than a file prevents use of this.

Comment: Were both loops supposed to have `IFS=`?

Comment: @thatotherguy no, just the second loop.

Comment: What does the IFS= do in the second loop anyway?

Answer (score 9):

The biggest difference is that in the pipeline, the `while` loop executes in a subshell, so if you change the values of any variables in the body of the `while`, those will be lost after the pipeline completes.

```
$ foo=5
$ cat file | while IFS= read -r line; do
>    foo=$line  # assume $line is not 5
> done
$ echo $foo
5
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
>  foo=$line
> done < file  # Assume one line with the word foo
$ echo $foo
foo
```

In `bash` 4.2, this can be mitigated by using the `lastpipe` option, which allows the last command in a pipeline to be executed in the current shell instead of a subshell.

Aside from that, the version using input redirection is more efficient, since it does not require extra processes to be started.

Comment: Good answer! I often forget about that variable scope thing when I just mention "useless use of cat" :)

Comment: But they both have while loops?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't explicit about which construct required a subshell; edited.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to chepner's observation about subshells, one of the loops uses `IFS=` and one does not.

`read` uses this variable to split up words. With one variable, this affects leading and trailing whitespace.

With `IFS=`, it's preserved:

```
$ IFS= read -r line <<< "   test   "
$ printf "<%s>\n" "$line"
<   test   >
```

Otherwise, it's stripped:

```
$ read -r line <<< "   test   "
$ printf "<%s>\n" "$line"
<test>
```

You can imagine how much havoc the first non-`IFS=` loop would wreck on e.g. a Python file.