# Find files and tar them with trailing or leading space in their name

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a script, that tries to archive the contents of a directory with `tar`:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /root/files -type f -name "1*" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    MYDIRNAME=$(dirname "${file}")
    MYFILENAME=$(basename "${file}")
    MYMODIFYDIR=$(echo "$MYDIRNAME" | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\//_/g' | sed 's/\ /_/g')
    MYMODIFYFILENAME=$(echo "$MYFILENAME" | sed 's/\//_/g' | sed 's/\ /_/g')
    GZIP=-9 tar -zcvf /root/"$MYMODIFYDIR"_"$MYMODIFYFILENAME".tar.gz "$file"
done
```

It does not work with files that have leading or trailing whitespace in their name. The error happens when reaching the file `/root/files/tetst\ test\ tgdjd/1\ 5765765\ 565765\` (**note** the trailing whitespace in the filename):

```
tar: /root/files/tetst test tgdjd/1 5765765 565765: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

The error given by tar has the trailing whitespace *trimmed* from the filename.

Comment: you could always run `tar` command with `.tar.gz` extension & then rename the file using `mv`.

Comment: The problem was that the file contains 1 5765765 565765 space at the end.

Comment: And the `/root/files/tetst test tgdjd/1 5765765 565765` file exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to reset `IFS` in the while loop, so the leading and trailing whitespaces gets treated as delimiter. Use this:

```
find /root/files -type f -name "1*" -print0 | while IFS= read -d $'\0' file
```

You could also add `-r` to read if there can be backslashes in the filenames.

See here for a more thourough explanation on `read` and `IFS`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26480210/1262699

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
tar -zcvPf /root/"$MYMODIFYDIR"_"$MYMODIFYFILENAME".tar.gz "$file"
```

Use the -P option to disable this feature.