# env -0 dump environment. But how to load it?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, env

The linux command line tool `env` can dump the current environment.

Since there are some special characters I want to use `env -0` (end each output line with 0 byte rather than newline).

But how to load this dump again?

Bash Version: 4.2.53

Comment: what do you mean with `load`?

Comment: @hek2mgl With "load" I mean to set these variables in a different shell.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't use `env`; use `declare -px`, which outputs the values of exported variables in a form that can be re-executed.

```
$ declare -px > env.sh
$ source env.sh
```

This also gives you the possibility of saving *non*-exported variables as well, which `env` does not have access to: just use `declare -p` (dropping the `-x` option).

---

For example, if you wrote `foo=$'hello\nworld'`, `env` produces the output

```
foo=hello
world
```

while `declare -px` produces the output

```
declare -x foo="hello
world"
```

Comment: Yes, works even if newlines are in variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load the export of `env` you can use what is described in [Set environment variables from file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969768/1983854):

```
env > env_file
set -o allexport
source env_file
set +o allexport
```

But if you happen to export with `-0` it uses (from `man env`):

> -0, --null
>             end each output line with 0 byte rather than newline

So you can loop through the file using `0` as the character delimiter to mark the end of the line (more description in [What does IFS= do in this bash loop: `cat file | while IFS= read -r line; do … done`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26480210/1983854)):

```
env -0 > env_file
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' var
do
   export "$var"
done < env_file
```

Comment: The first solution does not work in my case: `env > env_file` `set -o allexport` `source env_file` output `-bash: PROFILEREAD: readonly variable bash: 52052: command not found ... (a lot of command not found messages)`

Comment: The second solution (env -0) works, except: `PROFILEREAD readonly variable`

Comment: @guettli uhms, this is because that variable of yours is set to readonly. There are [some hacks on how to reset them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17398009/1983854)...

Comment: @guettli regarding the first comment, on sourcing the `env` alone, this is because new lines are considered new variables, so it confuses everything.

Comment: That's because the output of env isn't meant to be a valid shell script, which is what `source` expects. So if any variable has spaces, newlines, dollar signs, etc, those will be parsed by the shell as if they were in any other script. The top answer using `declare -p` is the right way to do this.