# When reading a line using While loop in bash, it's squezzing multiple space into one

Tags: bash, shell, unix, quoting

I am writing a shell Script to read the number of blank space into a file.

I am using following template to read line one by one

```
 while read l 
 do

 done <filename
```

but It's converting multiple spaces into one space while reading a line.

Comment: `while IFS= read l` ...

Comment: You left out the important part. How do you use the variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does IFS= do in this bash loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26480210/5639677)

Comment: while IFS= read -r l
        do
                echo $l
                echo $l>temp
                wc -L temp|cat >length

                len=`cut -d " " -f 1 length`
                echo $len

              
        done<$fname
this is my code

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i tried your suggestion but it's still replacing multiple spaces with one space.

Comment: You must quote your variables. `echo "$l"` otherwise word-splitting occurs when you `echo`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akash, you are running into problems because you are failing to quote your variables which invites *word-splitting* of output from `echo` (and any of the other commands) giving the impression that whitespace was not preserved. To correct the problem, *always Quote your variables*, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r l 
do
    echo "$l"
    echo "$l" > tempf
    wc -L tempf | cat > length
    len=$(cut -d " " -f 1 length)
    echo "$len"
done < "$1"
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat fn
who -all
           system boot  2019-02-13 10:27
           run-level 5  2019-02-13 10:27
LOGIN      tty1         2019-02-13 10:27              1389 id=tty1
david    ? :0           2019-02-13 10:27   ?          3118
david    - console      2019-02-13 10:27  old         3118 (:0)
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash readwspaces.sh fn
who -all
8
           system boot  2019-02-13 10:27
40
           run-level 5  2019-02-13 10:27
40
LOGIN      tty1         2019-02-13 10:27              1389 id=tty1
66
david    ? :0           2019-02-13 10:27   ?          3118
58
david    - console      2019-02-13 10:27  old         3118 (:0)
63
```

Also, for what it is worth, you can shorten your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r l 
do
    printf "%s\n%d\n" "$l" "${#l}"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Yep. This is just one of the many things that can go wrong when you don't put double-quotes around variable references.

Comment: I can't say I've never done it to myself either `:)`, but after about the 10th time it starts to sink in...

Comment: Thank You so much @DavidC.Rankin. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your scripting.