# How to delete users listed in a file ( Ubuntu Bash):

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, ubuntu

I have been trying to write bash code which deletes all users listed in a txt file in Ubuntu, however I am not sure how to do this.

For example say that the text in a file has two users, A and B. What I am trying to figure out is how to actually delete the users A and B from the system.

This is my pseudocode:

```
numusersdel = wc -l userstobedel.txt 
for ((i=0;i < $numusersdel; i++)); do
    usertobedel = grab the username of the user from number line i
    deluser $usertodel
done
```

Please suggest how I can solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop and `read` the file `userstobedel.txt` line by line:

```bash
while IFS= read -r usertobedel
do
    deluser "$usertobedel"
done < userstobedel.txt
```

`IFS=` and `-r` are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479562/what-does-ifs-do-in-this-bash-loop-cat-file-while-ifs-read-r-line-do).