# Difference in `< <(cat file)` and `<file` feeding loop

Tags: bash, file, while-loop, pipe, cat

I saw the following example for reading a file in a bash script:

```
while read IP; do
  ${IPTABLES} -I INPUT -s "${IP}" -j DROP
done < <(cat "${BLACKLIST}")
```

but I'd have thought to do the following instead:

```
while read IP; do
  ${IPTABLES} -I INPUT -s "${IP}" -j DROP
done <${BLACKLIST}
```

Why would one use `< <(cat` instead of simply `<`? What is the right-est way to do this?

Second comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26471631/2043621) gives good reason why using `cat` is bad but RoseHosting.com seems pretty reputable and they suggest the code above that uses `cat`. I'm thinking the `< <(cat file)` looks like a weird way to cover up a bad practice. [(here's another place it was pointed out `cat` piping to a loop is bad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552402/cat-file-vs-file)

Comment: As far as I'm aware the `cat` version is never preferable. It is purely more costly and less portable.

Comment: Here's the code source for the `< <(cat file)`: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/blocking-abusive-ip-addresses-using-iptables-firewall-in-debianubuntu/

Comment: *shrug* people cargo-cult and/or write poor shell scripts all the time.

Comment: @EtanReisner which is exactly what I'm trying *not* to do here. I went through the script line by line and understand all but that usage.

Comment: `cat` is useful when you want input from more than one file.  So, if the code were `cat "$BLACKLIST1"  "$BLACKLIST2"`, then `cat` would be useful.  In RoseHosting's case,  it seems completely useless.

Comment: `cat` might have use when reading from some non-file locations that might behave badly with whatever the shell does internally but which `cat` handles more gracefully (open errors ending up with empty input versus some other failure or something) but I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: Sounds reasonable but even in their script the file existence is checked right before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [useless use of cat](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cat_(Unix)#/Useless_use_of_cat). The only legitimate reason one might use it with a *single* file is for legibility (e.g. `cat file | while ...`), but in this case it only becomes more convoluted.